# Linking unwind library statically results in core dump

Tags: c++, exception, libunwind

This code, compiles with g++ using -std=c++11. Linking with g++, when **libunwind** is linked in statically program crashes after catching in **exerciseBug** (after rethrow).
LDFLAGS that result in crash:

> -Wl,-Bstatic -lunwind -Wl,-Bdynamic -llzma

when **libunwind** is linked in dynamically, code works as normally. LDFLAGS that result in normal operation:

> -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-Bdynamic -lunwind -llzma

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void exerciseBug()
{
  try {
    throw exception();
  } catch (exception &err) {
    cerr << "caught in exerciseBug\n";
    throw;
  }
}


int main()
{
  try {
    exerciseBug();
  } catch (exception &err) {
    cerr << "caught in main\n";
    ::exit(0);
  }
}
```

Question is *why is does libunwind need to be dynamically linked in?*
(Running on Ubuntu 16.04; g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609)